# How to handle many Dropdownlists

Tags: c#

I have an simple GUI with 7 Tabs.
Those Tabs represent "Categories" and in each of those Tabs are nine Comboboxes . Where the 7th Tab is an Default- Config.
The Data for the Comboboxes in the different Tabs is always the same. And the Data in the Comboboxes in the same Tab is different.
 I am saving all that Stuff in Objects where one Object stands for one Tab, so every Objects saves 9 Variables.

I would like to know how to group the ddl´s in one Tab together or something like that.
Because at the moment I would have to populate 63 Boxes...and then check if an User selected something.
And I made the GUI with the Designer, I guess it would be easier to do it programatically with Arrays?

```
   Eg.:
    List<Thing> nutrients = combobox1List();
    List<Thing> fat= combobox2List();
     ......
    box1.DataSource = nutrients; //Tab1
    box2.DataSource = nutrients;..... //Tab1

     box1.DataSource = nutrients; //Tab2
    box2.DataSource = nutrients;..... //Tab2
```

And that for every Tab 9 times. Now the User can select one of those things and I want to save it.

So, how do I properly populate the Boxes and deal with the Selection?

And is it possible to iterate over the Elements of Category (There is the Selection saved)? 
Because after the User selected the Comboboxes it´s choosen which Tab to use:

```
  switch(Tabs){ case Tab1: Category.ele1 = Tab1Combobox1Selection;break;
  ..........case Tab2: Category.ele1 = Tab2Combobox1Selection;
```

That would be a little bit much to write so how to automate it?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: If your question is about screen design irrespective of programming language and technology, your question might be suitable on another site on StackExchange, perhaps _UX_.  You would need to rewrite your question accordingly for the UX site I suspect and remove the c#-yness of your question.  [Here's an example recent well-written question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89723/how-to-display-gamification-progress-when-100-completion-of-a-task-might-not-be).  Screen design and UX typically happens before coding

Comment: @caesay It is in WinForms    And Micky it is not about UX it is only about how to program it so that I dont have to access 63 Comboboxes separately...